# Why is this simple jQuery not working?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this jQuery get request:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), { "searchExpression": "schroders" }, function (result) {

    // do stuff

}, "html");
```

Which sends the get request to this Action Method:

```
public PartialViewResult Tabs(string searchExpression)
{
    return PartialView(new SearchViewModel
    {
        PagedFunds = _fundService.GetFunds(searchExpression)
    });
}
```

The `$.get` request sends a request to the `Tabs` method, but `searchExpression` is always an empty string. I've done this before and it's worked.. does anyone have any idea why either the data isn't being sent or the Model Binder isn't working?

**edit:** I've just discovered the version of jQuery being used is 1.2.6. Also, There's another JS framework being used on the site - Prototype, I think - so this is the complete function that I'm using for the GET, which manages the compatibility issues:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.ActionControl a').click(function () {
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), { searchExpression: "schroders" }, function (result) {

            // do stuff

        }, "html");

        return false;
    });
});
```

does this offer any clues? Thanks

Comment: dave - i did a test on this in a little test app with jquery 1.4.2 and it worked perfectly. it could be related to the version in use and/or the clash with prototype. you might have to alias the $.get function to jQuery.get (i think that's the syntax)

Comment: Thanks jim.. I also did a test in another project and it worked. I'm now an enemy of Prototype! I'll give your suggestion of the alias a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is the the answer to the *real* issue is outlined here:

[How to send jQuery $.get so the Model Binder can bind a string to a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362147/how-to-send-jquery-get-so-the-model-binder-can-bind-a-string-to-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug it for the get parameter by firebug?
See the params that you are sending through ajax.

If not solved than let me know.

Comment: I've updated the message with a couple of points that might be having an impact on the success.

Comment: ... btw - I checked with firebug, and I can see that `?searchExpression=schroders` is getting sent in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Dave - could be that you need to explicitly decorate the action - i.e.:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
```

to ensure that it's not looking for a put/post request etc. I had wondered about the 'html' part previously, but that would only be related to the return type.

see comment above - but to put it in the answer:

**dave - i did a test on this in a little test app with jquery 1.4.2 and it worked perfectly. it could be related to the version in use and/or the clash with prototype. you might have to alias the $.get function to jQuery.get (i think that's the syntax)**

see http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

jim